# Android: How to Distribut Weight Evenly

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create an android activity that looks like the one below this. This one has 4 layouts and one has a scroll view. When I add layouts, they get put on the bottom of each other or off the screen. How can I make them fit on one screen.

[image]

Comment: Plz, paste your layout xml explaining what you have achieve so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [layout parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) for `LinearLayout` can take a `weight` attribute that you can use to divide space in a relative fashion among its child views. If, for instance, you want to give two buttons in a LinearLayout the same space, you can set the layout weight on both to the same non-zero numeric value (doesn't matter what the value is as long as its equal, i.e. 0.5/0.5 will do just as 1/1):

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" ... />
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't forget to set the dimension of the axis along which you want the view to grow to 0, i.e. if you want to stretch horizontally, set `android:layout_width="0px"`.

Comment: Be sure to set the height = 0dp so or else they will not be equal. Heights eat up space, then the left over is divided according to weight.